# How to set start and end time in daily scheduler in windows

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I want create scheduler Task on windows. I want to run this task daily.It should be start at 8:00 AM and stop at 6:00 PM and repeat it in every 30 mins. How to set this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the task schedule, create new task.
Under Triggers tab, the following are the options

Begin the task : **on a scheudle**
Settings
Choose **Daily** radio button
Start : start date  and time must be 8:00 AM
**Recur every**  1  days

Advanced Settings

Check the "Repeat task every" 30 Minutes  for a duration of 10 hours (This can type in the dropdown box)

"**Expire:**"  give the date and time when it should expire may be a month or more whatever.

Check "**Enabled** " checkbox.

I hope this will work.